# Label ContentStringFormat with new line

Tags: wpf, label, multibinding

I try to add new line inside `Label ContentStringFormat`:

```
Content="{Binding Path=(my:MyData.Files)}"
ContentStringFormat="{}Number of files:\n {0:#,0}"
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What is the putput you're getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use C# escape characters in XAML code. For XAML there are other possibilities:

- HEX represenation of CR/LF `&#x0d;&#x0a;` (or just line feed `&#x0a;`):

  `ContentStringFormat="{}Number of files: &#x0a; {0:#,0}"`
- Bind to string that initially contains new line charachters where you need them
- Use multibinding with `Environment.NewLine`

  ```
  <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{2}{1}" Mode="OneWay">
      <Binding Path="Property0" />
      <Binding Path="Property1" />
      <Binding Source="{x:Static System:Environment.NewLine}"/>
  </MultiBinding>
  ```