# Add newline to Stringformat in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

I'm binding the columnheaders of a datagrid to an observablecollection of dates, to display the day and date in the columnheader. This works fine. However, I would like to add a newline or break using the string. How can this be done?

```
<DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DataContext.Week.Days[1].Date, StringFormat=ddd dd.MM.yyyy, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
```

This displays the following Text: Tue 06.12.2016 
What I want it to display is

Tue
06.12.2016

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the TextBlock's `Inlines` property:

```
<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding DataContext.Week.Days[1].Date,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}">
    <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=ddd}"/>
    <LineBreak/>
    <Run Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyyy}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I had to set `Mode=OneWay`, but works fine me though. Thanks!

Comment: `Mode=OneWay` was already in the answer. However, check if the modified XAML also works for you.

Comment: Works as well with less text. Thanks again!

Answer (score 17):

For folks looking to put a newline in StringFormat (or ContentStringFormat, if you need to use Label), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794822/316760) has a way. You can use:

> HEX represenation of CR/LF `&#x0d;&#x0a;` (or just line feed `&#x0a;`):

So, for the code in question:

```
StringFormat=ddd&#x0d;&#x0a;dd.MM.yyyy
```

Answer (score 2):

StringFormat isn't always an intuitive syntax, but I prefer Vimes solution in combination with TargetNullValue over the accepted solution.

It means I can only add a line-break if the second run has a value

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run Text="{Binding Message, Mode=OneTime}" />
  <Run Text="{Binding Exception, Mode=OneTime, TargetNullValue='', StringFormat={}&#x0d;&#x0a;{0}}"  />
</TextBlock>
```